# Indexing in oracle database tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I was working on creating indexes on a few columns in my table

Q1: what is difference between creating indexes on a single column(id-'separate',column1-'separate') and columns combined(id,column-'Combined')?

To add more details-id is not a unique key in my table

Q2: Would the index on combined columns speed up my query when i filter data by both columns in the where clause?

Please let me know about this.

Also,good resources that can help me understand more about indexes is welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

AVG

Answer (score 1):

it is different, it depends on your queries
    considering a table T(A,B,C)
    if you have only queries with "where A=V1 and B=V2", you'd rather index on (A,B)
    if you have queries  with "where A=V1" and others with "where B=V2" , you'd rather go with 2 indexes
    if you have both types of queries , you'd need an index (A,B) and another index(B)

Comment: In my case I had two tables(A:id,name,addr, B:id,employer_name). The number of values for id are around 100k and the number of values for employer name are just 15. A is left outer joined to B and I have my select clause picking up ID from A and Employer_name from B and where clause with conditions on Employer_name. My assumption was since we are searching ID's by their employer_name-creating a multiple column index would speed my query.. please let me know if am wrong

Comment: so table A should be already indexed on id , but for table B if the id is a key there is no need to index on employer_name, and if not ther should be some gains on having a combined index (i'm only guessing that you didn't show on table A the foreign key to B)

Answer (score 1):

A1: 
If your select is based on COLUMN1 and COLUMN2 separately, then go for two indexes.
If you are not going for UNIQUE, then drop the idea of composite indexes.
Also keep in mind that when you add index, you add more space overhead, inducing performance issue during huge inserts/delete. It shows good performance only on Select and update.

A2: This is not possible. Most likely case is that the index will never be used.

Comment: In my case I had two tables(A:id,name,addr, B:id,employer_name). The number of values for id are around 100k and the number of values for employer name are just 15. A is left outer joined to B and I have my select clause picking up ID from A and Employer_name from B and where clause with conditions on Employer_name. My assumption was since we are searching ID's by their employer_name-creating a multiple column index would speed my query.. please let me know if am wrong

Comment: Assuming that Id's are the only join, go for a single column index on both the tables.